# Сlosing a specific WebSocket

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

In my Angular project, I use WebSockets that open when clicking a button.
There are several such buttons on the page.
If you press, for example, 3 buttons, 3 connections will open respectively.
When each socket is opened, a different payload is transferred to it in accordance with the button pressed.

Now if you click on the button again, for example, 1, then the first socket connection should be closed, but in reality, no matter what button you click, the connection that was last opened is permanently closed, and the rest connections remain open.

Hence the question, how to close a specific connection from several previously opened ones?

websocket.service has standard methods:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {
  private ws: WebSocket;
  socketChanges$: Subject<MessageEvent> = new Subject<MessageEvent>();
  private isConnected: boolean;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  async connect(payload): Promise<void> {
    this.ws = new WebSocket(`${ socketUrl }?token=${ token }`);
    this.ws.onopen = (data: Event) => {
      if (this.ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        this.isConnected = true;
        this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ payload }));
      }
    };
    this.ws.onmessage = (data: MessageEvent) => {
      this.socketChanges$.next(data);
    };
    this.ws.onerror = (error: Event) => {
      //
    };
    this.ws.onclose = (data: CloseEvent) => {
      //
    };
  }

  private reconnect(): void {
    //
  }

  disconnect(): void {
    this.ws?.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll achieve this by maintaining an array of WebSocket instances with some identifier to associate each WebSocket connection with its button

```
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class WebsocketService {
        private websockets: Map<string, WebSocket> = new Map < string, WebSocket> ();
        private isConnected: Map < string, boolean > = new Map < string, boolean > ();

        constructor() { }

        async connect(buttonId: string, payload): Promise < void> {
            const ws = new WebSocket(`${socketUrl}?token=${token}`);
            ws.onopen = (data: Event) => {
                if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    this.isConnected.set(buttonId, true);
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ payload }));
                }
            };
            ws.onmessage = (data: MessageEvent) => {
                // Handle incoming messages here
            };
            ws.onerror = (error: Event) => {
                // Handle WebSocket errors here
            };
            ws.onclose = (data: CloseEvent) => {
                // Handle WebSocket closure here
                this.isConnected.set(buttonId, false);
                this.websockets.delete(buttonId);
            };

            this.websockets.set(buttonId, ws);
        }

        disconnect(buttonId: string): void {
            const ws = this.websockets.get(buttonId);
            if(ws) {
                ws.close();
            }
        }
    }

    websocketService.disconnect("button1");
```

Comment: Yes, I also found such a solution. I thought there was another solution. Either way it works.

Comment: @Alex glad to know it works, please do post if you find any other solution, happy to learn